# Show markers in radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create map filtering by radius and my location from example of acf field functionality because it's working in wordpress but have problem with showCloseLocations() function. Everything is working fine exept with that function because it's not showing only markers in radius.

Problem is somewhere in somewhere in geocoder.geocode if, after runing function on click it's removing radius and markers but not updating with new radius and markers in it.

Can someone help what I'm doing wrong or what's is missing?

```
(function($) {
function render_map( $el ) {

    var input_address = document.getElementById('radius_input_address');
    var radius_input = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius_input_field').value, 10)*1000;

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input_address);
    var inputBox = document.getElementById('radius_input_field');

    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
    var args = {
        zoom        : 8,
        center        : new google.maps.LatLng(51.919438, 19.14513599999998),
        mapTypeId    : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
    map.markers = [];
    $markers.each(function(){
        add_marker( $(this), map );
    });

    //My location marker and radius
    var myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: 'https://toobokn.psdes.pl/wp-content/themes/toobok/img/myLocationMarker.png',
        title: 'Moja Lokalizacja'
        //position: faisalabad
    });
    addYourLocationButton(map, myLocationMarker);

    var myLocationMarkerRadius = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: "#9BCCDF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#9BCCDF",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        //center: latlng,
        radius: radius_input,
        draggable: false
    });
    myLocationMarkerRadius.bindTo('center', myLocationMarker, 'position');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(inputBox)
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(radius_src_btn)
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(only_in_radius_btn)

    // SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var place = searchBox.getPlaces()[0];
        if (!place.geometry) return;
        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          myLocationMarkerRadius.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(12);
        }
    });

    window.updateRadius = function() {
        var radius_input = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius_input_field').value, 10)*1000;
        myLocationMarkerRadius.setRadius(parseFloat(radius_input));

        console.log('radius updated');
    }

window.showCloseLocations = function() {
    var i;
    var geocoder;

    if (myLocationMarkerRadius) {
        myLocationMarkerRadius.setMap(null);
        myLocationMarkerRadius = null;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
        if (map.markers[i]) {
            map.markers[i].setMap(null);
            map.markers[i] = null;
        }
    }

    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode(myLocationMarker, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

                    var myLocationMarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                    myLocationMarkerRadius = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: myLocationMarker,
                        radius: radius_input,
                        clickable: false,
                        map: map
                    });

                    if (myLocationMarkerRadius) map.fitBounds(myLocationMarkerRadius.getBounds());
                        for (var j = 0; j < map.markers.length; j++) {
                            (function (location) {

                                var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
                                var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLocationMarker, marker_lat_lng);

                                //distance in meters between your location and the marker
                                if (distance_from_location <= radius_input * 1000) {
                                    var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: marker_lat_lng,
                                        map: map,
                                        title: location.name
                                    });

                                    google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function () {
                                        if(infowindow){
                                            infowindow.setMap(null);
                                            infowindow = null;
                                        }
                                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {
                                            content: '<div style="color:red">'+location.name +'</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
                                            size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
                                            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30),
                                            position: marker_lat_lng,
                                            map: map
                                        });
                                    });
                                    markers.push(new_marker);
                                }
                            })(map.markers[j]);
                        }
                } else {
                    alert("No results found while geocoding!");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}

    // Your Location Button
    function addYourLocationButton(map, marker) {
        var myLocMapBtn = document.createElement('div');
        var myLocationMapBtn = document.createElement('button');
        myLocationMapBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.border = 'none';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.outline = 'none';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.width = '28px';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.height = '28px';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.borderRadius = '2px';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.marginRight = '10px';
        myLocationMapBtn.style.padding = '0px';
        //myLocationMapBtn.title = 'Your Location';
        myLocMapBtn.appendChild(myLocationMapBtn);

        var myLocationMapBtnIcon = document.createElement('div');
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.margin = '5px';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.width = '18px';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.height = '18px';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-1x.png)';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        myLocationMapBtnIcon.id = 'my_location_img';
        myLocationMapBtn.appendChild(myLocationMapBtnIcon);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
            $('#my_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        });
        myLocationMapBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var imgX = '0';
            var animationInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if(imgX == '-18') imgX = '0';
                else imgX = '-18';
                $('#my_location_img').css('background-position', imgX+'px 0px');
            }, 500);
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    map.setCenter(latlng);
                    clearInterval(animationInterval);
                    $('#my_location_img').css('background-position', '-144px 0px');
                });
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                $('#my_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
            }

            radius_input;
            myLocationMarkerRadius.setRadius(parseFloat(radius_input));
            myLocationMarkerRadius.bindTo('center', myLocationMarker, 'position');

            //map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(12);
            console.log('my location updated');
        });
        myLocMapBtn.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(myLocMapBtn);
    }

    center_map( map );
    markerCluster( map.markers, map )
    return map;
}
// end render_map function

// Add Marker / Markers
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {
    //var image = '/icon.png';
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
    var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : latlng,
        map : map,
        //icon : image
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });
    map.markers.push( marker );
    if( $marker.html() ) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : $marker.html()
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent($marker.html());
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close();
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('markers added');
}

// Center Map
function center_map( map ) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
        bounds.extend( latlng );
    });
    if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 10 );
    } else {
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }
}

// Group Markers
function markerCluster( markers, map ) {
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    //console.log( markers );
    console.log('markers grouped');
}

// Render Map
var map = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.acf-map').each(function(){
        map = render_map( $(this) );
    });
});
```

})(jQuery);

updated and chenged:
showCloseLocations() should be -> window.showCloseLocations = function()

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Whole function is working with wordpress and acf fields like map field,
I can't post example here because it want work

Comment: Your "whole code" isn't a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding semicolons after these?

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(inputBox)
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(radius_src_btn)
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(only_in_radius_btn)
markerCluster( map.markers, map )
```

Couldn't post in comments. Just a suggestion might fix it might no.

Comment: Actually, semicolons are optional. But in a few case it indeed needs semicolon. Here, with or without semicolons, makes no difference.

Comment: Suggestion in worth nothing unfortunately.
Read again what's not working in whole function

Comment: As I said it might or might not fix the issue, was only the thing stood out.